# In the 800 kyr $\ce{CO_2}$ record, how detectable would a short-term peak be?

Tags: climate-change, paleoclimatology, co2, literature-request

It is stated in https://cdiac.ess-dive.lbl.gov/trends/co2/ice_core_co2.html that the temporal uncertainty for the glacier $\small\mathsf{CO_2}$ records is less than $\small\mathsf{5~\%}$ at any given moment. That means ‒ for example ‒ ca. $\small\mathsf{5,\!000}$ years at $\small\mathsf{100,\!000}$ years ago.  Could there have been peaks in the $\small\mathsf{CO_2}$ record that rose and fell back so quickly we wouldn't be able to detect them? Is there some paper or perhaps a monography that lists all the possible events in Earth's history that could have occurred in the last $\small\mathsf{800,\!000}$ or more years, which would lead to a likewise fast $\small\mathsf{CO_2}$ increase as today's, but also showing that, on the other hand, any such events would leave a long-lasting trace in the $\small\mathsf{CO_2}$ that should be easily detectable in the record?

I've found out that part of the answer is already in answers to [this question](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/18141/is-there-any-natural-phenomenon-that-can-account-for-the-100-fold-faster-co2-rat).

Comment: It's not clear what the remaining part of your question is. Could you edit it? The resolution of the record is annual layers. I think the "temporal uncertainty" refers to the cumulative uncertainty due to disturbed/missing sections of the core.

Comment: I believe Degauss is asking about the detectability of hypothetical short-lasting peak in the CO₂ record.  I don't know if such peaks (rising *and* falling very quickly) are physical, but the question of detectability is a valid one.

Comment: Hi Degauss, welcome to the site.  We were not entirely sure what you meant.  I have edited your question for clarification, please [edit it again](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/posts/18409/edit) if this was not was you intended.

Comment: You had edited it so well I didn't spot the difference at first. :D First I thought it would be too dumb to ask for peaks that were just "quick" but I admit that now it is more readable.

Answer (score 2):

$\small\mathsf{CO_2}$ does not fall back quickly:

> graph shows the IPCC 2007 $\small\mathsf{CO_2}$ liftime from a computer model run that shows what happens to a single instantaneous pulse of $\small\mathsf{CO_2}$ emitted to the atmosphere. One thousand years after the $\small\mathsf{CO_2}$ is emitted to the atmosphere 20% is still there according to this model.
>   [only zero carbon](http://www.onlyzerocarbon.org/carbon_dioxide.html)
>   [image]

The decline shown is mostly due to $\small\mathsf{CO_2}$ dissolving in the oceans.